# I need the background color of my body coming, before the background image

Tags: css

the background of the "main" part of the homepage(marked in red), should be black but because of the image, it cannot be seen. This is my code:

```
body {
    color: white;
    font-family: futura;
    background-color: black;
    font-size: 15px;
    max-width: 700px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    background: url(Website_Bilder/background.png) 
    no-repeat center center fixed;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
}

head {
    font-size: 30px;
    display: block;
    position:relative;
    background-position: center;
    background-size: cover;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    text-align: center; 
}

section {
    font-size: 15px solid #a0a0a0;
    border: 50px;
    padding: 0%;
    clear: ;
    margin: 1em auto;
}

ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #333;
}

li {
    float: left;
}

li a {
    display: block;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
}

/* link color */
li a:hover {
    background-color: #111;
}

img {
    width: 100%;
    float: center;
    height: auto;
    max-width:100%;
    display: block;
    margin: 1em auto;

    left:0px;
    top:100px;
    z-index:-1; 
}

p { 
    padding 10px 20px 10px 20px;
    margin 20px;
}
```

and this is what I get:

[image: rendered web page]

/I made better screenshot and added more code

Comment: use background-image, else background-color is reset to none if not in the rule with the image ... Your image doesn't tell much ?

Comment: Does the background image have all that blue?

Comment: Can you show some more code, so we can see the issue for ourselves. Right now, I'm not entirely sure, but I think the solution would be to move some of the styles from the `body` to the `html`.

Comment: Sorry, i made a better picture.

Comment: Try to wrap all your DOM elements inside a div and set its background-color: black;, set body's z-index:-1

Comment: @Pushpendra Thanks bro

Comment: Your code isn't right. `head` is an element and that doesn't appear inside the window, then what is the CSS rule for. and padding should have a colon like this `padding: 10px 20px 10px 20px;`. try writing proper code otherwise it can mess up your project.

Answer (score 0):

In case that I understand you correctly: You want your red bordered area to have a black background instead of the image that is defined as background in your CSS body selector? Then you just have to define a new CSS class/id for the html tag that surrounds this area, like this:

```css
html, body {
 height: 100%;
 width: 100%;
}

body {
    color: white;
    font-family: futura;
    background-color: black;
    font-size: 15px;
    max-width: 700px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    background: url(http://tub.tubgit.com/reimg/resize-img.php?src=http://photos.up-wallpaper.com/images251/jdicnfzws24.jpg&h=1080&w=1920) 
    no-repeat center center fixed;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
}

div.redArea {
 min-width: 70%;
 height: 100%;
 background-color: black;
 text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link href="style.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
 <div class="redArea">
  <p>this is a test</p>
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

The width of the redArea class has to be defined as min-width because you have set the max-width of your body selector to 700px.